# Diff vs xtreg different results in Stata

Tags: econometrics, stata, difference-in-difference, treatment-effect

I am trying to perform a DiD with three different methods. Here is an example of my dataset (the complete data is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7wain5p6jib1gmm/teste.dta?dl=0)), where "regime" is the treatment that starts in 2007 and goes until 2019:

```
code_7    regime    ano    cap_1
1100015    0    2002    1
1100015    0    2004    0
1100023    0    2000    5
1100023    0    2001    4
1100023    0    2002    2
1100023    0    2003    4
1100023    0    2004    1
1100023    0    2005    1
1100023    0    2006    1
1100023    0    2007    0
1100023    0    2008    4
1100023    0    2009    1
1100023    0    2010    1
1100023    0    2011    3
1100023    0    2012    1
1100023    0    2013    2
1100023    0    2014    1
1100023    0    2015    0
1100031    0    2000    1
1100031    0    2001    0
1100031    0    2002    0
1100031    0    2003    
1100031    0    2004    0
1100031    0    2005    
1100031    0    2006    0
1100031    0    2007    
1100031    0    2008    0
1100031    0    2009    0
1100031    0    2010    0
1100031    0    2011    0
1100031    0    2012    0
1100031    0    2013    
1100031    0    2014    0
1100031    0    2015    0
1100056    0    2000    1
1100056    0    2001    0
1100056    0    2002    0
1100056    0    2003    3
1100056    0    2004    0
1100056    0    2005    0
1100056    0    2006    0
1100056    0    2007    1
1100056    0    2008    1
1100056    0    2009    0
1100056    0    2010    0
1100056    0    2011    0
1100056    0    2012    0
1100056    0    2013    0
1100056    0    2014    1
1100056    0    2015    
1100064    0    2000    0
1100064    0    2001    0
1100064    0    2002    0
1100064    0    2003    0
1100064    0    2004    1
1100064    0    2005    0
1100064    0    2006    1
1100064    0    2007    0
1100064    0    2008    0
1100064    0    2009    0
1100064    0    2010    0
1100064    0    2011    2
1100064    0    2012    0
1100064    0    2013    0
1100064    0    2014    0
1100064    0    2015    0
1100072    0    2006    0
1100072    0    2007    
1100072    0    2008    
1100072    0    2009    0
1100072    0    2010    0
1100072    0    2011    1
1100072    0    2012    
1100072    0    2013    0
1100072    0    2014    0
1100072    0    2015    
1100080    0    2000    1
1100080    0    2001    0
1100080    0    2002    1
1100080    0    2003    1
1100080    0    2004    2
1100080    0    2005    1
1100080    0    2006    0
1100080    0    2007    1
1100080    0    2008    0
1100080    0    2009    0
1100080    0    2010    1
1100080    0    2011    0
1100080    0    2012    0
1100080    0    2013    0
1100080    0    2014    2
1100080    0    2015    0
1100098    0    2000    1
1100098    0    2001    1
1100098    0    2002    1
1100098    0    2003    1
1100098    0    2004    1
1100098    0    2005    0
1100098    0    2006    1
1100098    0    2007    1
1100098    0    2008    1
1100098    0    2009    0
1100098    0    2010    0
1100098    0    2011    1
1100098    0    2012    1
1100098    0    2013    0
1100098    0    2014    2
1100098    0    2015    0
1100114    0    2000    2
1100114    0    2001    1
1100114    0    2002    2
1100114    0    2003    2
1100114    0    2004    1
1100114    0    2005    2
1100114    0    2006    6
1100114    0    2007    3
1100114    0    2008    1
1100114    0    2009    0
1100114    0    2010    1
1100114    0    2011    1
1100114    0    2012    1
1100114    0    2013    1
1100114    0    2014    2
1100114    0    2015    0
1100122    0    2000    6
1100122    0    2001    2
1100122    0    2002    5
1100122    0    2003    3
1100122    0    2004    3
1100122    0    2005    2
1100122    0    2006    1
1100122    0    2007    2
1100122    0    2008    2
1100122    0    2009    2
1100122    0    2010    1
1100122    0    2011    6
1100122    0    2012    0
1100122    0    2013    4
1100122    0    2014    1
1100122    0    2015    1
1100130    0    2000    0
1100130    0    2001    0
1100130    0    2002    0
1100130    0    2003    0
1100130    0    2004    2
1100130    0    2005    0
1100130    0    2006    2
1100130    0    2007    1
1100130    0    2008    2
1100130    0    2009    2
```

1. I followed [https://www.princeton.edu/~otorres/DID101.pdf](https://www.princeton.edu/%7Eotorres/DID101.pdf) in order to conduct the first exercise.

   xtset code_7 ano

   gen time = (ano>=2007) & !missing(ano)

   gen treated = (regime>0) & !missing(regime)

   gen did = time*treated

   xtreg lncap_1 did regime, fe

I got the following result:

```
Fixed-effects (within) regression               Number of obs     =      8,865
Group variable: code_7                          Number of groups  =      2,203

R-sq:                                           Obs per group:
     within  = 0.0315                                         min =          1
     between = 0.0018                                         avg =        4.0
     overall = 0.0124                                         max =         19

                                                F(2,6660)         =     108.20
corr(u_i, Xb)  = -0.0639                        Prob > F          =     0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     lncap_1 |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         did |  -.2287338   .0697029    -3.28   0.001    -.3653738   -.0920938
      regime |  -.1961217   .0680113    -2.88   0.004    -.3294456   -.0627977
       _cons |   .4644935   .0054163    85.76   0.000     .4538758    .4751111
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     sigma_u |  .39174852
     sigma_e |  .48458941
         rho |  .39523397   (fraction of variance due to u_i)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
F test that all u_i=0: F(2202, 6660) = 3.19                  Prob > F = 0.0000
```

2. The second exercise follows the next procedure used in [https://www.princeton.edu/~otorres/DID101.pdf](https://www.princeton.edu/%7Eotorres/DID101.pdf):

   xtreg lncap_1 time##treated regime, fe

The output is:

```
Fixed-effects (within) regression               Number of obs     =      8,865
Group variable: code_7                          Number of groups  =      2,203

R-sq:                                           Obs per group:
     within  = 0.0720                                         min =          1
     between = 0.0004                                         avg =        4.0
     overall = 0.0191                                         max =         19

                                                F(3,6659)         =     172.15
corr(u_i, Xb)  = -0.1177                        Prob > F          =     0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     lncap_1 |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      1.time |  -.2273705   .0133374   -17.05   0.000    -.2535161   -.2012248
   1.treated |  -.2152926   .0665886    -3.23   0.001    -.3458275   -.0847576
             |
time#treated |
        1 1  |   -.035354   .0691715    -0.51   0.609    -.1709524    .1002443
             |
      regime |          0  (omitted)
       _cons |    .529124   .0065182    81.18   0.000     .5163463    .5419017
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     sigma_u |  .39738564
     sigma_e |  .47438456
         rho |  .41235892   (fraction of variance due to u_i)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
F test that all u_i=0: F(2202, 6659) = 3.42                  Prob > F = 0.0000
```

3. Finally, the last exercise uses the command diff:

diff lncap_1, treated(treated) period(time) id(code_7)

```
DIFFERENCE-IN-DIFFERENCES ESTIMATION RESULTS
Number of observations in the DIFF-IN-DIFF: 8865
            Before         After    
   Control: 5924           2407        8331
   Treated: 80             454         534
            6004           2861
--------------------------------------------------------
 Outcome var.   | lncap_1 | S. Err. |   |t|   |  P>|t|
----------------+---------+---------+---------+---------
Before          |         |         |         |
   Control      | 0.493   |         |         |
   Treated      | 0.214   |         |         |
   Diff (T-C)   | -0.278  | 0.068   | -4.12   | 0.000***
After           |         |         |         |
   Control      | 0.374   |         |         |
   Treated      | 0.165   |         |         |
   Diff (T-C)   | -0.209  | 0.031   | 6.81    | 0.000***
                |         |         |         |
Diff-in-Diff    | 0.069   | 0.074   | 0.93    | 0.352
--------------------------------------------------------
R-square:    0.02
* Means and Standard Errors are estimated by linear regression
**Inference: *** p<0.01; ** p<0.05; * p<0.1
```

As you can see, I obtained three different values for the DiD estimator and I can not understand why it is happening. I wish someone here could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These specifications are very different. In the first case, you are creating a new dummy variable only if "year" and "regime" are equal to one, so the "DID" coefficient measures the differences of "ln_cap" when these last variables are true. According to this, such a specification doesn't take into account possible effects in the others scenarios. For instance, effects on ln_cap in the pre-treatment period.

In the second case, this problem is fixed, in fact, you can see this change in the F statistic. Finally, the last specification shows a coefficient value of 0.069 regarding -0.035 of the second specification. This difference is because the third model doesn't include the "regime" variable nor heterogeneity unobservable between observations (fixed effects).

For instance, if you run:

```
reg lncap_1 time##treated
```

you should receive the same third model's result.